# How do I redirect the console output and the command itself to a file?

Tags: redirect, command-line, console

If I can redirect the console output to a file, how do I also redirect the executed command itself??

Example:
ffmpeg -i videoFile 1> logFile.txt 2>&1

The logFile will not have as first row:
ffmpeg -i videoFile 1> logFile.txt 2>&1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear what your goal is here, so here are a few things to try. Also, always best to include a tag for OS or shell that you are using. I hope you're not really a Windows user:-)

Do you know about the `script` utility? You can run `script logFile` and any commands and output after that will be captured to `logFile`. The downside is that it captures *everything*. Do a quick test to see if that works for you. Also check `man script` for details about the inherent funkyness of your particular OS's version of script. some are better than others. `script -k logFile` may work better in this case.

Else, if you really, really need this, I would make a small shell script like:

```
cat ffmpegwrapper
#!/bin/bash
#  ffmpegWrapper
vidFile="$1"
echo ffmpeg -i "$vidFile"
ffmpeg -i "$vidFile"
```

Save it to a dir that is included in your PATH, ideally `/usr/local/bin`.

*If you want more flexibility with what (extra ffmpeg options) or how much (more files), can be processed from the cmd-line, you can experiment changing the reference for `"$1"` to `"${@}"`, which means "all arguments on the cmd-line, keeping quoted spaces as single arguments. i.e. cmd `1 "2 3" 4` has only 3 argments, with $2 having the value `"2 3"`. Just recall that `-i` will always be the first option that `ffmpeg` will see*.

Make it executable

```
chmod 755 ffmpegWrapper
```

Run it and capture output as you are already doing

```
 ffmpegWrapper videoFile  > logFile.txt 2>&1
```

note, now you don't need to type -i.

To see what is happening you may prefer to use the `tee` utility, like this

```
 ffmpegWrapper videoFile 2>&1 | tee logFile.txt
```

Don't forget that if you want a history to use append redirection in the first example, i.e. `>>` or the `-a` option to `tee`.

IHTH